# Powershell Get-Module shows installed, Uninstall-Module says not found

Tags: windows, powershell

How can a module be uninstalled so that Get-Module no longer reports it found?

```
> Get-Module -list -Name Pester

ModuleType Version    Name  
---------- -------    ----  
Script     3.4.0      Pester

> Uninstall-Module -Name Pester

PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'Pester'.
```

Comment: Try this: `Get-InstalledModule -Name Pester | Uninstall-Module`

Comment: @techguy1029 "PackageManagement\Get-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'Pester'."

Answer (score 5):

The following did a nice job of removing pester 3.4.0.
The following requires to be run with the parameter `-RunAsAdministrator`:

```
$modulePath = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester"
if (-not (Test-Path $modulePath)) {
    "There is no Pester folder in $modulePath, doing nothing."
    break
}

takeown /F $modulePath /A /R
icacls $modulePath /reset
icacls $modulePath /grant Administrators:'F' /inheritance:d /T
Remove-Item -Path $modulePath -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
```

The solution is taken [from GitHUB](https://gist.github.com/nohwnd/5c07fe62c861ee563f69c9ee1f7c9688).

I was then able to run the following...

```
Install-Module Pester -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

...and then validate.

**PS:**
The output of `C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-installedmodule` is:

```
Version    Name            Repository      Description
-------    ----            ----------      -----------
1.1.183.17 MSOnline        PSGallery       Microsoft Azure Active Directory Module for Wind...
4.9.0      Pester          PSGallery       Pester provides a framework for running BDD styl...
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This was a great pointer as the classical: uninstall-module for the Pester package failed no matter what I tried.

Comment: Is it same as open the module path with file explorer and then delete all files with admin permission?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the particular Software Package that you have mentioned is the fact that it is quite peculiar. *Pester* is a *PowerShell* Module that is used for testing *PowerShell* Modules.

Its Version that you have mentioned in your example, `3.4.0`, might also be the Version that comes installed with the *Microsoft* *Windows* *PowerShell* Integrated Shell-Scripting Environment (I.S.-S.E.) and that can also be updated.

Therefore, the Error Message that appears in your excerpt, produced by the `Uninstall-Module` *Microsoft* *Windows* *PowerShell* Command-Let might be misleading. It does not mean that the *Pester* Module does not exist, but that the *Microsoft* *Windows* *PowerShell* Environment does not allow its uninstallation. It has been coded this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OneDrive, you may be hitting this bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/509

It seems like Get-InstalledModule and Uninstall-Module do not properly handle a Documents folder that is a link to OneDrive and report that there are no modules installed.

Comment: This link is broken. @glucas, do you have another link to the issue?